# Merge the tags for the open source library Prophet

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Should we merge the two tags related to the Prophet library, [facebook-prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-prophet) and [fbprophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbprophet)?

How can we do that?

[image]

Comment: Why is it important that it is an open source library?